# Puppet - How to chage umask setting for the previlage user

Tags: linux, puppet

for changing the umask setting , i had created the puppet script which insert the line "umask 0027" in the file "/etc/profile" , but it doesn't show the umask value as 0027, when we echo the umask. but when we relogin then it show the value 0027. so it take effect only after relogin.

but we want the immediate effect of the change without relogin , so we added one more line to my puppet script as "source /etc/profile" but it doesnot work and gave the error as below

'source /etc/profile' is not qualified and no path was specified. Please qualify the command or specify a path.

Could somebody help me on this issue ?

my puppet file looks like below

---

```
exec {"modify-umask-entry":
  command => "sed -i 's/umask [0-9]\{3,\}/umask 027/g' /etc/profile",
  path    => "/bin:/usr/bin/",
}



exec { "/bin/echo 'umask 027' >> '/etc/profile'":
       unless => "/bin/grep -Fx 'umask[\t][0-9]{3}' '/etc/profile'",
  # onlyif => "/bin/grep -i 'umask[ \t][0-9]{3}' /etc/profile | wc -w",
}

exec {"seeting_new_umask":
  command => "source /etc/profile",
}
```

---

Comment: This question might be better placed at StackExchange's superuser site.

Comment: The problem may be this: `source` is not a linux command.  It is a bash command.  If puppet doesn't execute those instructions as a bash script, then `source` will always fail.

Comment: @KevinA.Naudé You should post that as an answer. The solution is to invoke bash with the command as an argument, i.e. exec{ 'foo': command => "/bin/bash -c 'source /etc/profile; ....'" }

Comment: @choover Unfortunately that won't work.  Setting the umask only has effect within the process that does it (see [`umask in sys/stat.h`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/umask)), and the sub-processes it spawns.  When that new bash instance terminates, the umask change will no longer have effect.